# how to clip text into OneNote 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2007

I'm looking for a way to simply highlight text and use a keyboard shortcut to import it into OneNote 2007.  Is that possible?  I know in Evernote, you could highlight something and press Windows key + A...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what it looks, Crtl-C is the best option...if it is from a website, it also copies the website's address.